# Issue returning user

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hey guys I'm having a bit of an issue returning user.

At the moment I'm able to bypass `user : discord.User = None):` if the command `getbio` is invoked alone it will just return the users `ctx.author` bio however, if I invoke the command `getbio @user` it won't return anything.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but here is how I'm trying to do this.

```
@commands.command()
async def getbio(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
     if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
        db = sqlite3.connect('profiles.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT profile FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.send ("Bio not set")
        else:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT profile FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            await ctx.send (str(result[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing any code is the user is not `None`.  Below is an updated command that simplifies the user logic into one line.

```
@commands.command()
async def getbio(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    db = sqlite3.connect('profiles.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT profile FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        await ctx.send("Bio not set")
    else:
        await ctx.send(str(result[0]))
```